# optimum way to calculate Euclidean distance in python

Tags: python, euclidean-distance

I have to calculate the euclidean distance between each row of the matrix to every other row. actually I have a matrix of dimensions 50325X2. I had tried the python's `scipy.spatial.distance_matrix()` but the space in RAM require to do so is more than 18GB. Is there any optimum way to do so.

Comment: *50325X2* Do you mean 50325 columns 2 rows xor 50325 rows 2 columns?

Comment: 50325 rows 2 columns